# Split array into comma separated list of values

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a bit of metaprogramming using `send` methods quite a bit.  I've been successful so far because the methods I'm `send`ing to only take one argument.

Example:

`client` is an API client

`@command` is a method on `client` taken as an option to a CLI utility

`@verb` is a method on `command` taken as another option in the CLI

```
def command_keys
  case @command
  when "something"
    self.command_options.slice(:some, :keys)
  end
end
```

Then I call the API client like this:

```
client.send(@command).send(@verb, command_keys)
```

This works since the methods all take a `Hash` as their argument.  The problem I've run into is when I need to send more than 1 parameter in `command_keys`.  What I'm wondering is the best way to handle the `command_keys` method returning more than 1 value.  Example:

```
def command_keys
  case @command
  when "something"
    return self.command_options[:some], self.command_options[:keys]
  end
end
```

In this case, `command_keys` returns an Array as expected, but when I try to pass that in the `send(@verb, command_options)` call, it passes it as an Array (which is obviously expected).  So, to make a long story short, is there some easy way to make this condition be handled easily?

I know `send(@verb, argument1, argument2)` would get me the result I want, but I would like to be able to not have to give my script any more implementation logic than it needs, that is to say I would like it to remain as abstracted as possible.

Comment: Yes, I know the title of this post sucks, I just couldn't think of a better way to word it.

Comment: If your only intent in using `send` is for metaprogramming and not bypassing access control to protected/private methods, consider using [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send) instead to more clearly indicate that intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use splat.  You might have to rethink the code a bit, but something like:

```
client.send(@command).send(@verb, *all_the_args)
```

Comment: I half suspected splat was the solution, I'm just not sure how to get the list of arguments back from that method into something I can actually splat

Comment: You could just always return an array from the method, but it should actually work even with non array values, I believe.  `send(:foo, *[bar]) === send(:foo, *bar)`

Comment: The `send(:foo, *[bar])` syntax is invalid, it sends the elements as the array, not its values.  The `send(:foo, *bar)` syntax works, but it breaks all of the instances where `command_keys` returns a hash, since it breaks the hash into its key/value pairs as an array.  I tried adding some logic around whether or not the returned value was an Array and then splatting if necessary, but it very much did not like that without removing the DRYness from the code.

Comment: At this point, the dryness of the code is of little concern, this solution worked well enough.  Thanks!